# How to open link with using puppeter wsendpoint

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I try to connect browser with wsendpoint like this :

```
(async () => {  


 const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/eedbdd50-cd25-472d-a701-a0302d9ffe2f'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com.tr');  
})();
```

this code can open new tab but do not go to link. It give error:

```
(node:2022) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Performance.enable): 'Performance.enable' wasn't found undefined
(node:2022) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.connect({
  browserWSEndpoint: 'your endpoint...'
}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com.tr');
});
```